What is a natural-sounding verb form for the word dorveille?
I am writing a poem and I found the word dorveille, which means to be in a state of being half asleep and half awake. Here's an example text:

In the preindustrial West, most people slept in two discrete blocks and used dorveille for all kinds of purposes... You could drink a cup of tea and take a satisfied leak on the embers of your fire. But everyone did something, because dorveille was ubiquitous. [1]

I want to use the form of dorveille as a verb; however it does not have an established verb form. Based on its etymology, it’s derived from the Old French words dormir (to sleep) and veiller (to be awake). My one attempt was the verb form dorveilling. However, this feels awkward to me. I don’t know how to come up with a better verb form that feels more natural to its origins. This is an excerpt from my poem:

Much did he love this dove.
For the softest coos
Of his slumbering flambeau
Melts the crow to swoon.
He felt much like a loon;
_____ himself far past noon.

(Simply: The crow loved the dove so deeply that when the dove, the flame of his passion, cooed softly in his sleep, the crow nearly fainted. He felt as if he were losing his mind, _____, thinking of him until the late afternoon.)
My question is: Is there a more fitting, one-word verb form derived from dorveille that I could use?

It seems to be a loan word from French. I can only find one dictionary reference with a brief search: Wiktionary. Can you please show a sentence with a blank – as a place holder, to illustrate how you intend to use a verb form of an obscure word?

What's a "slumbering flambeau"? And the line following it? "Melts a crow to swoon"? It's not clear to me at all what that could mean.

@user405662 Poetic language there. Flambeau (referring to the dove) was an allusion to the old adage of calling the object of one's passion their flame. So a Flambeau would be a flame you hold up in high-regard. Whereas, "Melts the crow to swoon (over him)" is to become more tender or loving to the point that you swoon or faint.

Do you need himself?

The logical verb would be dorveille. Although it's not listed anywhere, and even reveille doesn't seem to be used as a verb. But compare English verbs reconnoitre or sauté.

The least appealing blank is the made-up verb. I'd use your own losing, or "daydreaming now far past noon," or sleeping, dazed, romanced, pining, frozen, wading, and such. Even if you don't mind interrupting your reader to go off to a dictionary for an odd word, you don't want to hint that the crow or duck becomes a duvet on any level.

OED and Wiktionary list the word sleepwaking (not sleepwalking), which is the equivalent portmanteau in English. However, it is neither a common nor a natural-sounding word. Although, you are writing a poem so it would be acceptable, as French neologized dorveille also.

Concerning your first quote, here's a quote from Wikipedia: "[Erkrich] found no common word in English for the period of wakefulness between [two periods of sleep], apart from paraphrases such as first waking or when one wakes from his first sleep and the generic watch in its old meaning of being awake. In Old French an equivalent generic term is dorveille, a portmanteau of the French words dormir (to sleep) and veiller (to be awake)."

How the heck would you pronounce that in English?

Maybe:

Dozing himself far past noon.

AH:

doze  (dōz)
v. dozed, doz·ing, doz·es
v.intr. To sleep lightly and intermittently.
v.tr.  To spend (time) dozing or as if dozing: dozed the summer away.
n.  A short, light sleep.

Godefroy

dorveiller, v. n., être à moitié endormi.
La dorveillant plus d'une courte peur
M'épeurera plus vostre ombrage trompeur.
(Vauq., Idill., I, 80.)
Elle dorveille en douce paix.
(Id., ib., II, 55.)


Dozing himself? I don't think doze is used like that.

@user405662 Neither did I but I found hundreds of occurrences of it in books. I'm not native anyway so that's the reason why I wrote maybe.

"Dozing far past noon" fits the meter.

@WeatherVane Thanks, answer updated.

Uh, no. Where you see dozing himself, himself is not a reflexive pronoun; it’s an emphatic one. The guard was asleep and the criminal himself was dozing.

@TinfoilHat Do you think I should remove himself from my reply to make clear it doesn't work? Crossing it out isn't enough? Here is the kind of sentence I found: She glanced toward the other side of the room, where Avery slouched in a chair, apparently dozing himself.

I think striking out the word that was in the original, to emphasize it is unnecessary, is OK.

Your cross-out is fine. Just noting that one does not doze one’s own self. You are trying to read himself as a reflexive pronoun, but doze is intransitive. Look at the sentence above your example to understand how himself is used as an emphatic pronoun. Something like:  Speaking of sleeping... even Avery was dozing.

@TinfoilHat Yes, it's clear now. Thanks.

He felt much like a loon;
drowsing far past noon.

drowse verb
2. intransitive. To be drowsy; to be heavy or dull with or as with sleep; to be half asleep. Also with away, off. 1598–
[selected attestations] 1853   Drowsing
and dreaming with half-open eye. —Tait’s Edinburgh Magazine vol. 20
615 1886   He..now and then drowsed away into
a half sleep. —W. W. Story, Fiammetta ii. 39 Source:
Oxford English Dictionary (login required)


Good find! It has the required sense "to be half asleep".

You could use lie dormant:

Sleeping, lying asleep or as asleep; hence, figurative intellectually asleep; with the faculties not awake; inactive as in sleep.

Some Romans were lying dormant, in the sun.
N. Hawthorne, Journal 18 March in French & Italian Notebooks (1980) iii. 134
(OED)


If you decide to use it, you don't need himself:

... lying dormant far past noon.


I think 'dormant' comes from the same French verb dormir too.

@WeatherVane Yes, it does.

'Lucid dreaming' is the right sort of thing - awake enough to be in control, but also to watch the dream. It would fit if you drop the 'himself' which it does not need.
'Surveiller' in English becomes 'to surveil', which suggests 'dorveil'. If you are writing poems for crossword-solvers, that might do.

I recommend the under-appreciated Vanilla sky
